# Active Directory standard users can reset passwords for other user accounts

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, password-reset

Active Directory, recently and we ran a pen test found out that standard users can reset the password for other user accounts.

They categorized this as "Insecure DACL Permissions".

I tried locating the specific permission granted to that grants the reset password permission to remove it, but I couldn't find a permission that applies to "domain users" and grants them the ability to modify password of other objects.

I would like to know if there's a tool that could generate a report of who has which permissions in this environment and how can I tackle this issue in general and deny domain users the ability to reset other user's passwords.

We do allow users to reset their own passwords and we have an hybrid environment where password writeback is allowed.

This is what shows under the root permissions of AD:
[permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUtOL.png)

This is what I see under the "effective permissions" of a domain user:
[effective access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHqdt.png)

It is possible that someone delegated permissions in the past to perform password resets to some group but I can't seem to be able to find it. There are 30-40 permission entries in the root of this AD and I really don't know which one of those permissions is the one allowing the password resets to happen.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The first screen shot there is a special permissions granted to Authenticated Users. Seems like a good start to click on it and examine the permissions.

Comment: I would simply test it, create two standard users, and try it if it's possible, to change the password without knowing the other persons password

Comment: You could create a PowerShell script, if you know the permission it's easier to create the script. If you enable audit logging and test it you might be able to locate the permission earlier (Advanced Auditing using a GPO)

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask for more detail from the pen testers, to be honest. As described, it's not clear whether the testers are saying ALL users can reset ALL other user passwords. Perhaps it's just ONE user (unprotected by AdminSDHolder (`adminCount` attribute = 1?)) that can reset ONE other user's password. Or all other permutations in between. The pen testers should provide at least one example or describe which DACL, and flag the potential scope of the issue.

In the meantime, where are your user accounts? Hopefully not many are in the default Users container (other than Administrator). The permission may be delegated at an OU level, so as suggested in comments, try creating a couple of new accounts in your accounts OU and see if one can reset the other's password (ensuring enough time for replication and for any account modification processes to take effect). Naturally, if you have multiple user account OUs, try it in each.

For a nice freeware tool that shows AD DACLs in a GUI interface and allows you to compare them between OUs and other nifty features, as well as other AD and LDAP-related utilities, I highly recommend NetTools (https://nettools.net/).

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script shows the ACL and enables auditing

```
# Import the Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Specify the AD root path
$adRootPath = "DC=yourdomain,DC=com"

# Get permissions for the AD root
$acl = Get-Acl "AD:\$adRootPath"

# Output all permissions
$acl.Access | Format-Table

# Enable auditing for password changes and resets
$auditPolicy = Get-ObjectAcl -Path "AD:\$adRootPath" -Audit
$auditPolicy | Add-Ace -Principal "Everyone" -AuditRights "WriteProperty" -ApplyTo "ThisObjectOnly"
$auditPolicy | Add-Ace -Principal "Everyone" -AuditRights "ExtendedRight" -AuditType "DS-Replication-Get-Changes" -ApplyTo "ThisObjectOnly"
Set-Acl -Path "AD:\$adRootPath" -AclObject $auditPolicy
```

You could also use tools like Bloodhound of AD ACL scanner they should be able to show the insecure ad permissions